# Input an array of data in one input field

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Not sure how to explain this but I was wondering if there is a simple way to input an array of data for a single input field.

For example, input field 'vacancies'
"vacancies": [
       15,18,16
]

Similarly to this:
[image]

I've seen React-select and select2 does this but is there another way to it?

Comment: Do you want to show same tags shown in picture or just want to get multi values in code after selection?

Comment: Just multiple values, it doesn't have to look exacly like how select2 does

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to implement something like this is to use [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) and [list attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdeflist), not sure if style can customize UI of these tow inputs,

if you want to have control over how it looks exactly like the snapshot you provided, then you have to implement custom component and use HTML, CSS, JS

here is a working snippet of native HTML implementation, also not the [compatibility with browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple#email_input):

**Update**: this doesn't work on all browsers, `multiple` attribute doesn't work for some browsers also may behave differently, I should have included this before the edit but didn't state this firmly, so here quote from MDN doc linked above:

> If and only if the multiple attribute is specified, the value can be a
>   list of properly-formed comma-separated e-mail addresses. Any trailing
>   and leading whitespace is removed from each address in the list. If
>   the required attribute is present, at least one email address is
>   required.
>
> Some browsers support the appearance of the list of options from the
>   associated  for subsequent email addresses when multiple is
>   present. Others do not.

```html
<!-- Use , to add select another value.  -->
<input type="email" list="emails" multiple>
<datalist id="emails">
 <option value="first@example.com">
 <option value="second@example.com">
 <option value="third@example.com">
 <option value="last@example.com">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Not able to add second value

Comment: I updated my answer to include what the documentation says about it, not sure about other browsers, this works in chrome, anyway if the OP wants to have similar functionality with the same look and feel of select2 he must use it or create his own implementation.